# How to set read timeouts between fixed packets of bytes?

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

I am developing an application in Visual C++ 2008 which is supposed to read some data received from a hardware device through a serial interface. The data is sent in packets of 45 bytes every 50 milliseconds. I am using the functions provided by the WIN32 API to do all the necessary tasks like open and close the ports.

This is my [reference](http://xanthium.in/Serial-Port-Programming-using-Win32-API).

In it the author mentions the process of setting timeouts to wait for data

```
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 50; // in milliseconds
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50; // in milliseconds
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10; // in milliseconds
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 50; // in milliseconds
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10; // in milliseconds
```

The first member of the `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure is the wait time between two successive bytes. This is supposed to be 0 for me as I receive 45 bytes in one go and then it has to be 50 milliseconds while it waits for the next packet.

While setting up the DCB structure, will setting the byte size to `8*45` bits and then setting the `ReadIntervalTimeout` to 50 milliseconds work?

EDIT: It won't. I just read the definition of the byte size to be between 4 and 8. Any other way I could handle this?

Also can I set event handlers with these timeouts? I want to be able to keep the application running, while it reads only when it detects data. But I am afraid if on start the hardware device has already sent say 20 of the 45 bytes, the application might consider byte 21 as the first byte. Is this fear unfounded?

EDIT 2: I have modified my read function to the following to account for checking for the appropriate header

```
void CGCUGUIDlg::fnRead()
{
    char TempChar; //Temporary character used for reading
    char SerialBuffer[45];//Buffer for storing Rxed Data
    DWORD NoBytesRead;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        ReadFile( m_hComm,           //Handle of the Serial port
             &TempChar,       //Temporary character
             sizeof(TempChar),//Size of TempChar
             &NoBytesRead,    //Number of bytes read
             NULL);

        if(TempChar == 0x10||0x80)
        {SerialBuffer[i] = TempChar;// Store Tempchar into buffer
        i++;}
    }

    while (NoBytesRead > 0);
}
```

Comment: Your fear doesn't sound unfounded. Is there some way of distinguishing the end/start of a packet other than timing (which is a rather awkward thing to distinguish)? If not, can you add some unique framing which will allow your receiving app to synchrnoise with the packet boundaries.

Comment: It does have a predefined header and footer. There header will be either `0x10` or `0x80` and the footer will be either `0x1F` or `0x8F`. But how would I check for this? Also how would I set the 50 millisecond gap?

Comment: EDIT: I set the `ReadIntervalTimeout` to 50 milliseconds and the rest to zero. Does this mean that the application will wait an arbitrary amount of time before the first byte, then fill the buffer (whose size I'll set as 45) and then wait 50 milliseconds?

Comment: This cannot work correctly.  Timeouts are measured by the driver, it is completely out of sync with your program's execution.  You always need a protocol to group bytes together into a "message".  Simple ways are a unique final byte ('\n' usually) or a byte at the start of the message that indicates how many follow.  Ensuring that the receiver and transmitter are always synchronized, so the receiver doesn't try reading a "message" in the middle after opening the port, usually requires a unique start byte.

Comment: @HansPassant So will my edited read function do this as I have set the condition to check for a unique header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your receiving app you need to implement your protocol - your code needs to start off "unsynchronized" which means in your case it looks for a header and footer the correct number of bytes apart, and throws away data until those are found. When they are found, the protocol is "synchronized" and the packet is sent on for consumption, and the protocol always keeps checking for the header/footer - if found, the data is accepted as a packet, if not found the state reverts to unsynchronized. Your code looking for a packet should accumulate data and once synchronized must only consume the packet length off it, i.e. if you receive 46 bytes, consume the 45 then keep adding data to the remaining 1 byte until you have 45 or more, and don't discard the more. When you get that working you won't need to worry about the gap between packets. The usual approach is that you maintain a buffer to which received bytes are added, and from which data is consumed leaving what hasn't been consumed to be added to as the next packet - this way you don't need your code to worry about timeouts between packets, or unexpected processing delays, etc.

Comment: So if I am assured that the header and footer will be 43 bytes apart, can I reduce my synchronisation condition to just look for the header? I have added my modified read function in above.

Comment: Can your header byte appear in those 43 bytes? If so you have stronger need to ensure you are actually detecting the real header. For me, if you're getting the footer anyway you may as well use it. You have to assemble the following 43 bytes after the header so you may as well wait for the 44th and check it.

Comment: You are reading the incoming data a byte at a time which doesn't seem terribly efficient (but can probably be fixed up later), and I don't see how your code handles the byte after the header (when i>0), and I don't see how your code  checks the footer (when i==43 and another character has been received) and only then sends the accumulated message off to be processed. Work in Progress, I'm assuming.

Comment: Might be a good (defensive) approach to make sure you log the occurrence of synchronisation _and_ loss of sync.

Comment: `Work in Progress, I'm assuming.` oh it most definitely is. I need to learn and code at the same time. Also I meant to place `i++` outside the `if` loop. Also, what did you mean by the byte after the header? Won't it just get added to the buffer if the `if` clause is satisfied? I am reworking the code to include the footer condition as well.

Comment: Work out the logic - TempChar is the data byte read from the serial port, it is only the header value once, the next time round TempChar is not the header value, it is the first byte of the actual data and needs to get stored in the correct place. Having i++ inside the if statement is OK because you only step to the next location once the header has been received. But once the header has been received you should unquestioningly put the next 44 bytes into the buffer and check the footer - yes?

Comment: Oh! I cannot believe I was so thick! Ok, so I will write a `fnCheckSync` boolean function that will first read the bytes until it receives the header, then it will read and store into a buffer till it receives the footer. If the size is 45, it returns `true`. If this is true, only then will my application start reading and storing actual data.

Comment: Also, if this is true, in my actual read function can I change `TempChar` to a byte array rather than a single `char`? Would that allow me to read 45 bytes at a time given that I have confirmed synchronisation?

Comment: Yes, but you need to then handle the situation where you actually receive less than 45 bytes, perhaps because of a timeout or because the hardware device has been disconnected/switched off. Basically it gets more complex to manage the data and you might want to move to e.g. a longer circular buffer that you add received data to the end of and consume data from the front of.